# What are some traditional Iraqi Minhagim?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

I'm a Sefaradi Jew of Iraqi descent, but my dad is not religious. I have looked in books like "A Treasury of Sefaradic Laws and Customs", but they tend to not have Iraqi specific Minhagim. I would love to know more about my heritage and customs, supposedly my great-grandfather was Hakham in Iraq, but we've lost all the traditions.

Anyone on this site know any Iraqi customs or traditions?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.seforimcenter.com/product.asp?numPageStartPosition=1&P_ID=6934&strPageHistory=cat&strKeywords=&strSearchCriteria=&PT_ID=72

Comment: "A Treasury..." is the one written by Dr. dubrinsky? He focuses mostly on Syrian Jewry from what I understand

Comment: Check the Ben Ish Chai. The english translation has a nnice biography in the beginning which is short but informative. The rest of the sefer is a halachic sefer but the Ben Ish Chai discusses minhagim a lot and which one's he is introducing or which ones he is replacing. It is very interesting as the Ben Ish Chai spent a lot of his life reviving the Iraqi Jewish community after terrible pogroms. So the book is really a rebuilding of a society sort of.

Answer (score 5):

A huge resource for all things Jewish and Iraqi.

http://www.babylonjewry.org.il/new/english/index.html

Comment: I do love me some spinning text. Seriously though, thanks, this looks awesome.

Answer (score 2):

If you understand Hebrew this is a good site even if you don't the site has a translate option on top if you are using Google I think. http://hazzan.qpon.co.il/Front/Tools/homepage.asp